# Is this Axios post request incorrect?

Tags: javascript, http, post, axios

I use my local server for the react-native app and i got problem  with axios post request:

When using insomnia like this:

[image]

Everything is fine, I mean server response is `{ "status":"success" }` as I expected. But when it comes to axios:

```
axios
.post('http://192.168.1.41/meeter-from-here/backend/event.php', {
   sesionID: '',
   eventName: 'UserCreated',
   eventData: {
      username: 'faaafsdsd',
      email: 'bfdsfsbbf@bbb.com',
      password: 'ccccccccccc',
   },
})
.then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

There is no response.data. My question is that axios request exact equivalent of insomia's ? I have tried to modified it but the result is still empty body. (which mean incorrect request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need have strings in eventData,Try this:

```
eventData: {
      'username': 'faaafsdsd',
      'email': 'bfdsfsbbf@bbb.com',
      'password': 'ccccccccccc',
   },
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was stupid the problem was that axios.post(adr,body) send body as JSON not as POST form. So the solution is to do sth like: 
let form = new FormData();
form.append("name","val")
axios({...data:form,....});

Anyway thank you